# Declaration of setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTplTrait::setPageFormat(array $size, string $orientation) Laravel 5.4 and php 7

Tags: fpdi

Getting below declaration error on installing fpdf and fpdi package

```
Declaration of setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTplTrait::setPageFormat(array $size, string $orientation)
```

Comment: What version of FPDF are you using?

Comment: Fpdf version 1.8
Fpdi version 2.3

Comment: Update to FPDF 1.82 and FPDI 2.3.3.

Answer (score -1):

Try something this:

`composer.json`

```
"iio/libmergepdf": "^4.0",
"tecnickcom/tcpdf": "6.3.*",
"setasign/fpdi": "^2.0"
```

**Using Fpdi to sign a pdf**

```
use setasign\Fpdi\Tcpdf\Fpdi;

...

$pdf = new Fpdi('P', 'mm', 'A4');
$pages = $pdf->setSourceFile('file.pdf');
$certificate = file_get_contents('certificate.crt');

for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $page = $pdf->importPage($i);
    $pdf->useTemplate($page, 0, 0);
    $pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'tcpdfdemo', '', 2, array());
}

$pdf->Output($path, 'F');
```

**Using libmergepdf to merge two pdfs**

```
use iio\libmergepdf\Merger;
use iio\libmergepdf\Driver\TcpdiDriver;

...

$merger = new Merger(new TcpdiDriver);
$merger->addFile('file1.pdf');
$merger->addFile('file2.pdf');
$mergedPdf = $merger->merge();

return $mergedPdf;
```